# How to ignore if second select is null?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to calculate the account mutation (Credit - Debit)

This is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT
(SELECT sum(Transaction_Value) FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" AND Destination=99005571818061833)
-
(SELECT sum(Transaction_Value) FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" AND Source=99005571818061833)
```

**The expected result is:**
Return the account mutation value.

**The actual result is:**
null

The problem is if the 4th line did not find a row, it will return null regardless if the 2nd line return a value.

For example if we run the SQL statement to this table data:

```
ID  Date        Source              Destination         Transaction_Value
168 2020-11-24  SETORAN TUNAI       99005571818061833   1000000.0000
169 2020-11-24  98993563492155716   98993563492155717   1000.0000
```

The return value will be null because the SQL statement did not find a row with Source === "99005571818061833"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN Destination = 99005571818061833 THEN Transaction_Value
                WHEN Source = 99005571818061833 THEN -Transaction_Value
                ELSE 0
           END)
FROM transactions
WHERE Date BETWEEN 2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30' AND
      99005571818061833 IN (Source, Destination)
```

Comment: I liked you only use 1 FROM, I think this is a better solution. However, I tried to run this against non exists account number and it return a value of `1000000.0000`. I will try to adjust this query.

Comment: I found the problem. I tried to query against non exists account number e.g`SELECT * FROM bankaccount.transactions WHERE Destination=99005571818061836;` this query return the value for `Destination === 99005571818061833`. The datatype is CHAR(17) for the destination. I think that is the root problem. I will look up about CHAR.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out because I did not add " ", for example `SELECT * FROM bankaccount.transactions WHERE Destination="99005571818061836"` this will return null.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to SQL. This by no mean effective, if you have an answer with more effective way and an explanation, feel free to answer it. I will mark it as answer.

The answer:

```
SELECT
(SELECT sum(Transaction_Value) FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" AND Destination=99005571818061833)
-
IFNULL((SELECT sum(Transaction_Value) FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN 2020-11-01 AND 2020-11-30 AND Source=99005571818061833), 0)
```

The explanation:

It turns out if you substract a number with null, the return value will be null.

For example

```
SELECT
(SELECT sum(Transaction_Value) FROM transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" AND Destination=99005571818061833)
-
null
```

The expected result will be null.

So... logically if your 4th line return null, you should change it to 0.

Comment: You should cater for either source OR destination are null.

Comment: @P.Salmon Do you mean the select result => null or to prevent destination=null ?